# Importing multiple files setting the name with tostring

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I'm trying to import several matrices, which contain a pattern in the name. I create first their names in a table

```
    datalist := {matrix1, matrix2};

piecelist = 
  Rest[Cases[OwnValues[datalist], x_ :> ToString@Unevaluated@x, {3}]];

fileName1 = 
  Table[piecelist[[i]] <> ToString[time] <> "_" <> ToString[month] <> 
    "_" <> ToString[i1] <> ".csv", {i, 1, Length[datalist]}];

fileName2 = 
  Table[piecelist[[i]] <> ToString[time] <> "_" <> ToString[month] <> 
    "_" <> ToString[i2] <> ".csv", {i, 1, Length[datalist]}];
```

Thus I can call them at 2 different places, for instance with

```
time=1;
month=DateString["Month"];
i1=DateValue["Day"];
i2=i1-1;
```

Now I have the names and want to import them but with a specific an unrelated name. Once more I create the table with their new names:

```
datavar := {var1, var2};

piecelist2 = 
  Rest[Cases[OwnValues[datavar], x_ :> ToString@Unevaluated@x, {3}]];


    Table[piecelist2[[1]] <> ToString[j], {j, 1, 2}]
     
    Table[piecelist2[[2]] <> ToString[j], {j, 1, 2}]
```

Up to now fine, but I'm unable of doing the following correspondence

```
var11 = Import["/Users/ .....  fileName1[[1]]]
var12 =                        fileName2[[1]]


var21 = Import["/Users/ .....  fileName1[[2]]
var22 =                        fileName2[[2]]
```

inside a Do expression which takes care of the label and the indices in one go. So that when I ask for var21 shows fileName1[[2]].
Any help?

Comment: Since your variable names are strings, before you make assignments to them you must convert the strings to expressions.  Doing this on the left side of the = sign requires `Evaluate@ToExpression["varname"]`.  For example, `names = {"x", "y"}; vals = {2.72, 3.14}; Clear @@ names; Thread[
 Evaluate@(ToExpression /@ names) = vals]`  assigns the values to variables *x* and *y*.  Of course, your values would be `Import[ ... ]` instead of the example numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I wanted to link the rhs with lhs, something as Table[Table[Symbol[piecelist2[[k]] <> ToString[j]], {j, 1, 4}], {k, 1,
     Length[piecelist2]}][[1, 1]] = 
 Import["/Users/........", 
  Table[Table[
     Table[Symbol["fileName" <> ToString[j]], {j, 1, 4}][[i, k]], {i, 
      1, 4}], {k, 1, Length[piecelist2]}][[1, 1]]]

Comment: Without actually trying it myself, it looks like using `Symbol` should work, but you will need `Evaluate@Symbol[ ... ] = ...` to make the assignment.  It may be easier to read if you use a single `Table` with 3 indices as in `Table[ ... , {i, ...}, {j, ...}, {k, ...}]`.  Note that it is simpler to use `Table[  Symbol[p] , {p, piecelist2}]` to loop over the names rather than using `Table[ Symbol[piecewise2[k]], {k, 1, Length[piecewise2]}]`.

Comment: yes, thanks a lot. It was the missing "Evaluate" what caused my trouble.